# Getting error when URL have year=2018 parameter in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am creating Booking Plugin for WordPress, so for Frontend, I'm getting error while i navigate calendar to 2018 year, it returns 404 not found error. Something like as follows:

`http://localhost/wordpress48/sample-page/?month=12&year=2017`

Above URL works perfect, also works perfect for all months.

But when i navigate to `year=2018` URL like as follows

`http://localhost/wordpress48/sample-page/?month=01&year=2018`

returns 404 not found error. Also nor works for other than current years.

I have save permalinks to **Post name** in WordPress Settings

**why isn't this code working?**

Comment: generally it will because 2018 doesnt exist

Comment: do you have any post that you are showing for 2017? and you dont have post for 2016 and 2018, thus

Comment: it goes to the archieve page, and archieve page will look for year , if it doesnt find any post for a particular year it wont work

Comment: i have edit post date and change its year to 2018, still it is not working. and for admin end everything works well. e.g. for 2018 or 2017 all. @Exprator

Comment: show you permalink settings

Comment: **Post name** is Checked `http://localhost/wordpress48/sample-post/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147331/discussion-between-dhruvang-and-exprator).

Answer (score -2):

Try save WP log to file (default: /wp-content/debug.log). And check it

You can do it via wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

if (WP_DEBUG) {
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
```